# JAVA How to generate a table of numbers in a specific range?

Tags: java, numbers, range, tabular

I'm curious as to how I should go about generating a vertical list of numbers in a specific range given by a user.

Say I have a user enter a low number and a high number and I want to display those numbers and every number between those numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Table {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    //Prompt user to enter low number 
    System.out.println("Enter the low number ");
    int lowNumber = input.nextInt(); 

    //Prompt user to enter high number 
    System.out.println("Enter the high number");
    int highNumber = input.nextInt(); 

    //Create table
    for (int i = 1; i <=256; i++){
        System.out.print(i);
    }
```

As you can probably tell, I am pretty lost.

Comment: `for (int i = lowNumber; i <= highNumber; i++) {`

Comment: And use `println` for vertical output.

Answer (score 0):

`IntStream.range(lowNumber, highNumber).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt user to enter low number 
        System.out.println("Enter the low number ");
        int lowNumber = input.nextInt();

        //Prompt user to enter high number 
        System.out.println("Enter the high number");
        int highNumber = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        //Create table
        for (int i = lowNumber; i <= highNumber; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter the low number 
15
Enter the high number
20

15
16
17
18
19
20
```